Can't install rpm packages from offline mirror: "No available modular metadata..."
I am trying to create an offline rpm repository that will allow me to install Docker to machines that won't have access to the internet.
I have created this Docker image for this purpose:
FROM almalinux:8.5 AS repo_builder

# Imports new AlmaLinux 8 GPG key
RUN rpm --import https://repo.almalinux.org/almalinux/RPM-GPG-KEY-AlmaLinux

# Install required packages
RUN yum install -yq createrepo_c python39 && \
    yum clean all

RUN mkdir -p /repos/rpm

# --- RPM repository

# Add the Docker repository
RUN dnf install -yq yum-utils
RUN yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo

# Install Docker packages
RUN dnf install -yq --downloadonly --downloaddir /repos/rpm docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin

# Create repository metadata with modular support
RUN createrepo_c --update /repos/rpm

The content of /repos/rpm is then served through an Nginx.
But after configuring one of the machines to reach this repository and I run the command dnf install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docke r-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin -y, I get these errors:
No available modular metadata for modular package 'container-selinux-2:2.229.0-2.module_el8.10.0+3858+6ad51f9f.noarch', it cannot be installed on the system
No available modular metadata for modular package 'fuse-overlayfs-1.13-1.module_el8.10.0+3859+6ae70a0e.x86_64', it cannot be installed on the system
No available modular metadata for modular package 'libslirp-4.4.0-2.module_el8.10.0+3858+6ad51f9f.x86_64', it cannot be installed on the system
No available modular metadata for modular package 'slirp4netns-1.2.3-1.module_el8.10.0+3858+6ad51f9f.x86_64', it cannot be installed on the system

I have check that the mentioned packages are well available in /repos/rpm.
I have no idea how to move on from this and my searches haven't been very fruitfuil. Appreciate any help, thanks.

To fix it, I had to edit my /etc/yum.repos.d/customrepo.repo on my client machine and add the line module_hotfixes=1:
[customrepo]
name=CustomRepository
baseurl=http://localhost:8080/rpm
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
module_hotfixes=1

I was then able to dnf install ... command to install docker.
